# JavaScript - Open file, search for string and print the next word

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, string

So i am looking for some help please ... What i want to be able to do is open a file that is stored locally on my server. Look for a particular word in the file and then print the next word when that particular word is found.

I have code that will open the file but it prints everything in that file.

```
<td class="hidden-phone">
<div id="test">
</div>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'http://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx/log-file.txt', true);
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}
function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('test');
        el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
    }
}
</script>
```

So lets say in that log-file.txt if the following:

```
Hello
Apples
World
foobar
```

I want to be able to open that file, search for the word Apples and if found print the next word which is World.

Comment: Managed to see your edit before it was declined; generally it's not a good idea to edit answers with your further problems, users needing further assistance usually just adds a comment below the (incomplete/unclear) answer and edit the question (with clear heading like "code updated according to XXX's suggestion" to keep the original question intact); anyways see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the content by a whitespace separator into an array of strings, roughly "words", then traverse the array and when the string (word) you are looking for occurs store the next array item:

```
var wanted = 'Apples';
var words = reader.responseText.split(/\s/);
var found = [];
words.forEach(function (word, index) {
    // if we've got the match and the next item exists (we're not at the end of the array)
    if (word === wanted && words[index + 1])
        // push the next item (word) to the "wanted" array
        found.push(words[index + 1]);
});
// join the results with line break elements and stuff them to el
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = found.join('<br/>');
```

If you need to search for more than one `wanted` word, use array & [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var wanted = ['Apples', 'Onions'];
// ...
    if (wanted.indexOf(word) !== -1 && words[index + 1])
```

(`indexOf` returns -1 if the element is not found.)

You example has more issues, the biggest of which I'd say is the `reader` scattered through several functions, it's generally better to keep it on one place and pass just the received content to the "business logic"  function (inside the onreadystatechange callback), so the updated example:

```
<button onclick="loadFile()">Load file</button>
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
function loadFile() {
    var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    reader.open('get', '/log-file.txt', true);
    reader.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (reader.readyState == 4 && reader.status == 200) {
            displayContents(reader.responseText);
        }
    };
    reader.send();
}

function displayContents(content) {
    var wanted = 'Apples';
    var words = content.split(/\s/);
    var found = [];
    words.forEach(function (word, index) {
        // if we've got the match and the next item exists (we're not at the end of the array)
        if (word === wanted && words[index + 1]) {
            // push the next item (word) to the "wanted" array
            found.push(words[index + 1]);
        }
    });
    // join the results with line break elements and stuff them to el
    console.log('found:', found);
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    el.innerHTML = found.length ? found.join('<br/>') : 'nothing found';
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are a legend ... Might I ask how you learnt all of this :)

Comment: Well there was no short way for me, just several years of scratching my head myself ;) Concerning web-related stuff, the best documentation site is probably [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), especially their [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) and [Learn web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) sections. (BTW if an answer solved your question mark it as accepted for others to see which solution to follow had they encountered the issue themselves.)